# MS Graph API how to reply to an email thread and maintain the message body from the previous emails like outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using MS Graph API to send reply emails from my UI. A user will select the message they want to reply to and they draft a email and add the contacts they want included (To, Cc, Bcc) and the new body of the reply email. I capture the message id of the email they want to send to and I reply to that. However, when they do this it the reply email does show up in outlook as if they are replying to the email because its in the chain/group of the associated emails but the body does not include the previous email threads similar to if you were to create a reply to email in outlook itself. Is there a way to include the historical email body threads like outlook or am I doing this incorrectly?

```
        public async Task SendReplyAsync(string EmailAccount, Email email, string MessageId)
    {
        var tries = 0;
        var maxRetries = 1;

        while (tries <= maxRetries)
        {
            tries++;
            try
            {
                var ToRec = new List<Recipient>();
                foreach (var address in email.To)
                {
                    ToRec.Add(
                    new Recipient()
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = address.EmailAddress,
                        },
                    });
                }

                var CcRec = new List<Recipient>();
                foreach (var address in email.Cc)
                {
                    CcRec.Add(
                    new Recipient()
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = address.EmailAddress,
                        },
                    });
                }

                var BccRec = new List<Recipient>();
                foreach (var address in email.Bcc)
                {
                    BccRec.Add(
                    new Recipient()
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = address.EmailAddress,
                        },
                    });
                }

                var attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();
                foreach (var attachment in email.FileAttachments)
                {
                    attachments.Add(new Microsoft.Graph.FileAttachment
                    {
                        Name = attachment.FileName,
                        ContentType = attachment.ContentType,
                        ContentBytes = attachment.ContentBytes
                    });
                }

                var message = new Message
                {
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Html,
                        Content = email.Body,
                    },
                    ToRecipients = ToRec,
                    CcRecipients = CcRec,
                    BccRecipients = BccRec,
                    Attachments = attachments,
                };

                await _graphServiceClient.Users[EmailAccount].Messages[MessageId].Reply(message, "").Request().PostAsync();

                tries = maxRetries + 1;

            }
            catch (ServiceException svcex) when (svcex.Message.Contains("Continuous access evaluation resulted in claims challenge"))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{svcex}");
                    string claimChallenge = WwwAuthenticateParameters.GetClaimChallengeFromResponseHeaders(svcex.ResponseHeaders);
                    _consentHandler.ChallengeUser(initialScopes, claimChallenge);
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    _consentHandler.HandleException(ex2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already solved it but I also came across the same problem and got it working (in a slightly hacky way).

I noticed that if you call the /reply endpoint and don't add any content, it does in fact include the previous message. However, if you include a ['body']['content'] it overrides the previous message body.

So basically just do a quick call to get the previous message to be appended and include it in the new body.

Assuming yo know the message_id from the original mail you want to reply.
Use the following graph endpoint to get the ['body']['content'] from the original message:

```
GET /me/messages/{id}
```

And before calling the /reply endpoint, prepare the ['message']['body']['content'], adding whatever text you want in front:
"This is a reply " + ['old']['body']['content']

```
POST /me/messages/{id}/reply
```

Email is sent with the reply and all the previous chains

Comment: If you want a non-hacky solution, the Graph API exposes a way to do this without searching for previous messages in the conversation. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the previous message bodies, you want to use the `Comment` field to do your reply message.

Assuming by your post that you are using Graph SDK Version 5.

**SOLUTION**

**SDK Version 5**

**Nuget Package Microsoft.Graph 5.40.0**:

The model you want to utilize is found under namespace -

`Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Messages.Item.Reply` and the model you want is `ReplyPostRequestBody`.

Your code should look like the following:

`````
using Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Messages.Item.Reply;
````
await _graphclient.Users[EmailAccount].Messages[MessageId]
.Reply.PostAsync(new ReplyPostRequestBody
{
      //Field supports HTML
      Comment = "{your response body}", //This is where you want to set your reply message
      //Message object should only be used to set attachments, and to, bcc, etc.
      Message = new Message 
      {
    
      }
 });
`````

This is documented by MSDN at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http